# sql and php variable

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database, image

i want to create form to upload file into img dir(i know how to do that),and insert an html code and php variable to database(that works fine), the problem is when i fetch the html code from database it shows `<img src=img/$rand>`, i what it to  show the the result of varible not the name, sorry for my bad english

here is my full code:

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing"); 


            $rand = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);

        ?>
          <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
            <h3 align="center">Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</h3>  
            <br />  
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />  
                 <br />  
                 <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info" />  
            </form>  
            <?php 
              if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
              $fu = $_FILES['image'];
              $image_tmp_name= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
              $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
              move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"img/$image_name");
              rename("img/$image_name", "img/$rand");

              //echo "<img class='iwalls' data-toggle='modal' data-target='' src='img/$image_name' alt='Loading...'>";
            }
             ?>
       <?php
    if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
      {  
  $file = '<img src=img/$rand>';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES ('$file')";  
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
  {  
       echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';  
  }  else{
    echo '<script>alert("Failed")</script>';
  }
     }  
     ?>
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <tr>  
                      <th>Image</th> 
                       <?php  
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images ORDER BY id DESC";  
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {    
              echo "<div>";
              echo $row ['name'];
              echo "</div>";

            }  
            ?>   
                 </tr>  

            </table>  
       </div> 

  </body>  
    </html>  
       <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#insert').click(function(){  
       var image_name = $('#image').val();  
       if(image_name == '')  
        {  
            alert("Please Select Image");  
            return false;  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            var extension =       $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();  
             if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) ==         -1)  
  {  
  alert('Invalid Image File');  
 $('#image').val('');  
  return false;  
   }  
    }  
       });  
        });  
          </script>
```

Comment: *(As you seem to care about how your code looks, search for auto indentation packages for you IDE/editor like Indentator for Brackets, auto-indent for Atom, etc)*

Comment: either `$file = "<img src=img/$rand>"` (double quotes) _or_ `$file = '<img src=img/' . $rand . '>'` (concatanate)

Comment: _but_ I'd recommend _not_ to save the complete html tag in your database. save the `$rand` only. What would you do when you decide to add a class to that image? Would be quite a hassle to change that in your database...

Comment: _and_ use prepared statements! You can get in trouble with quotes here.

Comment: yep, it worked,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using single quotes, the string will be as is it is.

```
 $rand = "hello.png";

 $file = '<img src=img/$rand>';
 // $file is <img src=img/$rand>
```

You need double quotes for string interpolation

```
 $file = "<img src=img/$rand>";
 // $file is <img src=img/hello.png>;
```

Comment: it worked!!!!!!!, i'm working on it for 3 days i tried every thing, but i didn't try that, thanks for your help